# functions not sharing valuess in python

Tags: python-3.x, variables, pygame

I am working on a game and i want to put the border collisions into a function to easily run. The function updates the co-ordinates so it cant move it off the screen but does not share these updated co-ordinates with the other function. So I cant move the image to it's new position. Please Help!

```
def collide(x,y,ctype):
    if ctype == "border":
        if x < 100:
            ob = 100 - x
            x1 = x + ob
            print(x,ob)
            return x,y


def main():
    x = 500
    y = 200
    while True:
        x,y = collide(x,y,"border")

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            #col = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(fRect, bRect)
            y -= dist
            side = "back"
        elif key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            y = y + dist
            side = "front"
        elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            x = x + dist
            side = "right"
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            x = x - dist
            side = "left"
        if side == "front":
            screen.blit(fPlayer, (x,y))
        elif side == "back":
            screen.blit(bPlayer, (x,y))
        elif side == "right":
            screen.blit(rPlayer, (x,y))
        elif side == "left":
            screen.blit(lPlayer, (x,y))
        #print(x,y)
        pygame.display.update()
```

These ore both functions that i want share x and y with.

Comment: For functions to "share" something with the code that called them, they should `return` it.

Comment: I tried returning the x value from the collide function and that didn't work

Comment: Then please show what you have tried.

Comment: you can use global

Comment: To use the returned values, you have to assign them again in `main()`: `x, y = collide(x, y, "border")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():
    town = "Pyllet Town"
    side = "front"
    if town == "Pyllet Town":   
        x = 500
        y = 200
        while True:
            screen.fill(white)
            screen.blit(grass, (0,0))
            screen.blit(sForest, (0,0))
            screen.blit(sForest, (1300,0))
            screen.blit(rfStrip, (140,775))
            screen.blit(house1, (300,150))
            screen.blit(house1, (900,150))
            screen.blit(house2, (300,250))
            screen.blit(house3, (900,250))
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
                if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
                    surface = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), pygame.RESIZABLE)
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                        backpack()


            x,y = collide(x,y,"border")
            x,y,side = move(x,y,side)  
            pygame.display.update()
```

Fixed the probom with doing x,y = collide(x,y,"border"). This also helped me reduce lag in my game and to make a move function. Thanks mkrieger1 for help!!!